N-Channel Highside MOSFET Circuit with an isolated buck converter gate schematic review
As the title suggests I have created this MOSFET circuit and was wondering if I could just get some people to review it and let me know any thoughts or concerns regarding it before I begin bread boarding it.

Description: I am using a 30s source so 90v min and 126v max and then converting down to 12v where I have a manual switch I will press and when I press it and close the circuit the mosfet should turn on and give power to the load. This obviously means this is static switching no frequency. Eg: on for an hour then off for an hour.
U1 is an isolated buck converter
D2 is a Zener diode serving for overvoltage protection incase the buck converter magically malfunctions
My questions:
Is it fine that I did not use a driver ic I just found no purpose of it in my application. And same with an optocoupler I thought since the buck converter is already isolated no point in an optocoupler.
In my circuit when the switch is open the mosfet is pulled to ground right?
Also like I said any other thoughts or concerns.

EDIT: I removed the R1 resistor completely. Was told from multiple sources it was unneeded and if anything made things worse.

Datasheet link to your IC please.

U3 will not work, emitter and collector should be swapped.

The Zener D2 should be physically and electrically as close to the FET
gate and source connections as possible. A Zener in this location can immensely improve the survival capability of a FET in adverse transient conditions.

Ok yeah that makes sense I will move the zener closer

For the love of self-preservation, please don't breadboard 100V stuff. Solder it to a perf board and pay extra attention to copper sizes vs currents.

You don't need a gate driver. I think your gate charge/discharge circuit is wrong. Usually it is in this confuguration:

Source: http://www.kynixsemiconductor.com/News/47.html
Zener is useful not only in the case of DC/DC converter failure.Your 96-126 can get easily coupled to the gate of your mosfet via parasitic capacitances. Also inductive load will generate a voltage spike on turn-off and the diode might not be fast enough.

This will not work with a supply voltage of 126 V at the FET drain.

It will, you just need to tie bottom side of R1 and collector of Q1 to the isolated DC/DC converter ground. R2 is the load.

Yes, then you might want to draw it that way. The current schematic only works if the PWM amplitude is much higher than the supply voltage and below the maximum gate voltage.

Yeah, sorry, not my schematic, I just wanted to illustrate the discharge circuitry.

Ok I see this now makes sense. Question though why does the placement of the resistor matter in my gate charge/discharge circuit im confused why you moved it?

@SRomie How could i solve the problem of the inductive load generate voltage spikes faster then my diode can react.

@RyanH A TVS rated for the same voltage as the zener should fix that. It is essentially just a fast, rugged zener.
